# google map V2 issue with jar file

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2, android-support-library

i have developed google Map v2 tutorial in February help of this [tutorial](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-google-map-v2-part-1.html).

### Its working fine at that time

my code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   package="com.djandroid.mapsv2"  
   android:versionCode="1"  
   android:versionName="1.0" >  
   <uses-sdk  
     android:minSdkVersion="8"  
     android:targetSdkVersion="16" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="com.djandroid.mapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />  
   <uses-feature  
     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"  
     android:required="true" />  
   <application  
     android:allowBackup="true"  
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  
     android:label="@string/app_name"  
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  
     <activity  
       android:name="com.djandroid.mapsv2.MainActivity"  
       android:label="@string/app_name" >  
       <intent-filter>  
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
       </intent-filter>  
     </activity>  
     <meta-data  
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"  
       android:value="API_KEY" />  
     <uses-library  
       android:name="com.google.android.maps"  
       android:required="true" />  
   </application>  
 </manifest>
```

---

my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  

   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"  
   android:layout_height="match_parent"  
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >  
   <fragment  
     android:id="@+id/fragment1"  
     android:layout_width="match_parent"  
     android:layout_height="match_parent"  
     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />  
 </RelativeLayout>
```

---

my Activity code:

```
package com.djandroid.mapsv2;  
 import android.app.Activity;  
 import android.os.Bundle;  
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {  
      @Override  
      protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {  
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
           super.onCreate(arg0);  
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
      }  
 }
```

**at that time i have used lib Project of `google-play-services` instead of `google-play-services.jar`. now I have update Android SDK. they give us `google-play-services.jar`
insted of google-play-services lib Project.**

### So, my question is : Why all code working fine with google-play-services lib project. but not working with google-play-services.jar??

### i want only reason why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are resources accessed in the jar file, which are generated via library project.

It's all about `com.google.android.gms.R` (specifically `R$stylable`) class file missing.